# Subset-join-replace using R data.table

Tags: r, join, replace, data.table, subset

I have a dataset consisting of id-name pairs. These pairs can appear multiple times. In some rows the value in the *name* column is missing, in others the *id* is missing:

```
id_name = data.table(stringsAsFactors=FALSE,
                 id = c("x123", "xy234","x123",NA,"z123","y123","d654","d654"),
                 name = c("john", "mary", NA,"mary","bob","bob", "john",NA)
                     )
```

I would like to replace **only** the *NA* values in one column with the (non-missing) value from another row, using the other column as lookup value. The result should be:

```
            id name
      1:  x123 john
      2: xy234 mary
      3:  x123 john
      4: xy234 mary
      5:  z123  bob
      6:  y123  bob
      7:  d654 john
      8:  d654 john
```

What is the idiomatic way of achieving this, the data.table way? The following approach for updating only the name column does not produce an error, but it does not update the dataset either :

```
id_name[is.na(name)][id_name[!is.na(name)], on="id", name:=i.name]
> id_name
      id name
1:  x123 john
2: xy234 mary
3:  x123 <NA>
4:  <NA> mary
5:  z123  bob
6:  y123  bob
7:  d654 john
8:  d654 <NA>
```

However, just subset-and-join without update works:

```
id_name[is.na(name)][id_name[!is.na(name)], on="id",nomatch=0L]

     id name i.name
1: x123 <NA>   john
2: d654 <NA>   john
```

**UPDATE**

Updated MRE to make clear that some names can be associated with 2 ids. Both ids have to be kept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for:

```
id_name[is.na(name), name :=
    id_name[!is.na(name)][.SD, on=.(id), x.name]
]
id_name[is.na(id), id := 
    id_name[!is.na(id)][.SD, on=.(name), mult="first", x.id]
]
id_name
```

Comment: I like your solution because it's a pure data.table approach

Answer (score 1):

We can group by 'name', 'id', and replace the NA elements in 'id' by the first non-NA value

```
id_name[, id := id[!is.na(id)][1], name]
id_name[, name := name[!is.na(name)], id]
```

-output

```
id_name
#     id  name
#1:  x123  john
#2: xy234 marry
#3:  x123  john
#4: xy234 marry
```

#### Update

We can use `fill` from `tidyr`

```
library(tidyr)
id_name1 <- id_name[, fill(.SD, id), name][,  fill(.SD, name) , id]
id_name1
#      id name
#1:  x123 john
#2:  x123 john
#3:  d654 john
#4:  d654 john
#5: xy234 mary
#6: xy234 mary
#7:  z123  bob
#8:  y123  bob
```

Comment: While this approach does update missing values, it also removes any additional records which might exist for the same id/name. The approach i'm looking for should update only the records with missing values without discarding other records.

Comment: @MariusPetruc can you please update your example with a more general one

Answer (score 0):

You can use `zoo`'s `na.locf` to fill the missing values.

```
library(zoo)
library(data.table)

id_name[, id := na.locf(id), name]
id_name[, name := na.locf(name), id]
id_name

#      id  name
#1:  x123  john
#2: xy234 marry
#3:  x123  john
#4: xy234 marry
```

Comment: data.table already have fillna function so extra packages are not needed

Comment: @jangorecki  Okay...I didn't know that, Thanks. However, it seems it works only for numeric values and not for character values?